# get a specific id value from a html string in javascript via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html string in a javascript variable and want to get the id value.

I converted it to pure html and than I tried to get the id value of the div.

```
var rowData = "<div class='multiid' id='3041' style='height:100%;' >test</div>";
var multiidhtml = $(rowData);
var multiid = multiidhtml.find('.multiid').attr("id");
```

The result should be `var multiid = 3041` but it does not work.

Comment: use `multiid = multiidhtml.attr("id");`

Comment: You don't need to do the find as the `.multiid` is the top level element in your jquery object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute *id* you are looking for is in the jQuery object itself. But `find(.multiid)` looks for elements with class *multiid* inside the object (as nested elements) which does not realy exists and the `attr()` returns *undefined*.

Try `multiidhtml.attr("id");`

```js
var rowData = "<div class='multiid' id='3041' style='height:100%;' >test</div>";
var multiidhtml = $(rowData);
var multiid = multiidhtml.attr("id");
console.log(multiid);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Consider the following example where you can use `find()` meaningful:

```js
var rowData = "<div id='3041' style='height:100%;' >test <p class='multiid' id='myParagraph'>Nested P</p></div>";
var multiidhtml = $(rowData);
var multiid = multiidhtml.find('.multiid').attr("id");
console.log(multiid);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`.find()` searches the descendants of the element, it won't match the element itself. You should wrap the HTML in another DIV so it won't be the top-level element.

```
var multidhtml = $("<div>", {html: rowData});
var multiid = multidhtml.find(".multiid").attr("id");
```

This is only necessary if `.multiid` might not be the top-level element. If it's always the top, use the simpler solution in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

.find() searches the descendants of the element, it won't match the element itself. SO use .closest() so that it searches from the root of selector DOM

```
var rowData = "<div class='multiid' id='3041' style='height:100%;' >test</div>";
var multiidhtml = $(rowData);
var multiid = multiidhtml.closest('.multiid').attr("id");
```

if you're sure that **id** attribute exists in the selected DOM you can directly find like this

```
multiid = multiidhtml.attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var rowData = "<div id='3041' style='height:100%;' >test <p class='multiid' id='myParagraph'>Nested P</p></div>";
var multidhtml = $("<div>", {html: rowData});
var multiid = multidhtml.find(".multiid").attr("id");
```